# androidstudio recyclerview and custom dialog

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick, dialog

I want to create a custom dialog with a recycler view on it. If I choose the recycler view cell and press ok button in dialog, then the textview will change. I created recycler view adapter, custom dialog, but I don't know how to connect dialog and adapter and what to put in onClick function..help me please..

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/writing_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexon"
        android:text="choose!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#341867"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/writing_dialog_ok"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexon"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textColor="#341867"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/writing_dialog_cancel"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textColor="#341867"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/writing_dialog_ok"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="355dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/writing_dialog_recy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recyclerview cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/dialog_radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexon"
        android:text="시리즈 1"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycler view adapter

```
public class WritingNovelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WritingNovelAdapter.Holder>{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<WritingNovel_data> dataList;

    public WritingNovelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WritingNovel_data> dataList){
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        protected ConstraintLayout dialog_container;
        protected RadioButton dialog_radio;

        public Holder(View view){
            super(view);
            this.dialog_container = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_container);
            this.dialog_radio = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_radio);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public WritingNovelAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.writing_dialog_cell, parent, false);
        Holder holder = new WritingNovelAdapter.Holder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WritingNovelAdapter.Holder holder, final int position) {

        String title = dataList.get(position).title;
        if(title.length() > 16){
            title = title.substring(0, 15) + "…";
        }
        holder.dialog_radio.setText(title);

        holder.dialog_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //????????????????????????????
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(dataList == null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return dataList.size();
        }
    }

}
```

custom dialog class

```
class CustomDialog {

    private Context context;

    public CustomDialog(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void callDialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.writing_novel_series_dialog);
        dialog.show();

        final RecyclerView writing_dialog_recy = dialog.findViewById(R.id.writing_dialog_recy);
        final Button writing_dialog_ok = dialog.findViewById(R.id.writing_dialog_ok);
        final Button writing_dialog_cancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.writing_dialog_cancel);

        writing_dialog_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        writing_dialog_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

====EDIT-1====

I call my dialog in here!

```
public class writing_novel extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 979;
    private RichEditor mEditor;
    private ColorPicker colorPicker;
    androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder textSizeDialogBuilder;
    private NumberPicker textPicker;
    androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder youtubeDialogBuilder;
    private EditText etYoutubeUrl;
    private Button writing_novel_btn_series;
    private ImageButton writing_novel_novel_ibtn_next;



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:{
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_writing_novel);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.writing_novel_main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        writing_novel_novel_ibtn_next = findViewById(R.id.writing_novel_novel_ibtn_next);

        writing_novel_novel_ibtn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(writing_novel.this);

                builder.setTitle("정말 다음으로 넘어가시겠습니까?").setMessage("다음으로 넘어가기전, 한번 더 검토해주세요.");

                builder.setPositiveButton("넘어가기", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(writing_novel.this, decide_novel_title.class);
                        
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("취소", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });

        writing_novel_btn_series = findViewById(R.id.writing_novel_btn_series);

        writing_novel_btn_series.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("id", "");
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
                dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "id");

                CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(writing_novel.this);
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "CustomDialog");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to figure out how to display the RecyclerView list of items, and when an item is clicked, show its data in a TextView below. Please correct me if I am wrong.

For the first step, you are close. All you need to do is instantiate a new layout manager and an instance of your adapter class, and pass them to your RecyclerView.

Add this to your CustomDialog class:

```
public void callDialog() {
    ...

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    writing_dialog_recy.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    // I'm assumming you are passing a list of data here
    WritingNovelAdapter adapter = new WritingNovelAdapter(context, dataList);
    writing_dialog_recy.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
```

As for showing the text in the textView, you have a few different ways to implement this. Its hard to say without seeing the rest of the related code, but I would recommend implementing a callback interface and calling the method from your ViewHolder, like so:

1. Define the interface in your Adapter class

```
public interface CallbackInterface {
void showText(String text);
}
```

2. Implement a callback interface in your CustomDialog class and implement the `setText` method, which is where you will set the text in the TextView. This will require that you have an instance of the TextView that you want to show that text in, meaning you must call this somewhere: `TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView8);`

```
class CustomDialog implements CallbackInterface {
... 

    public void showText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

3. Pass an instance of your CustomDialog to the adapter (make sure to redefine adapter constructor to accept an instance of CustomDialog

```
public void callDialog() {
    ...

    // I'm assumming you are passing a list of data here
    WritingNovelAdapter adapter = new WritingNovelAdapter(context, dataList, this);
    writing_dialog_recy.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
}
```

4. Call the callback method from the adapter class when the recyclerview cell is clicked

```
public class WritingNovelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WritingNovelAdapter.Holder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<WritingNovel_data> dataList;
    private CallbackInterface callbackInterface;

    public WritingNovelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WritingNovel_data> 
    dataList, CallbackInterface callbackInterface){
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.callbackInterface = callbackInterface;
    }

    ...

    holder.dialog_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                callbackInterface.showText(title);
            }
        });

}
```

## Edit #1

Your comment stated that your dialog is not showing up. Unless you left some code out of your CustomDialog class, this is because all your CustomDialog class is, is a Java class. You need to extend a superclass such as AlertDialog or DialogFragment. I'll do my best to summarize how to do this, but you should take a look at the android docs -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Here is an example of a DialogFragment you could try creating:

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment implements CallbackInterface {

    private Context context;
    private TextView textView;
    private RecyclerView writing_dialog_recy;

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /* This is the method which builds and essentially shows the dialog */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate your view that contains the recyclerview
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        // Your text view where you want to show the text after an item is clicked
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        // Your recyclerview in your custom_dialog.xml
        writing_dialog_recy = view.findViewById(R.id.writing_dialog_recy);

        // Create the layout manager
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        writing_dialog_recy.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Create and set the adapter
        WritingNovelAdapter adapter = new WritingNovelAdapter(context, dataList, this);
        writing_dialog_recy.setAdapter(adapter);

        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do whatever you want when user clicks the positive button
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create(); // return the dialog builder

    }

    public void showText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Then in whatever activity you are creating this dialog from, you show the DialogFragment and pass it the activity's FragmentManager and a tag

```
CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(this);
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "CustomDialog");
```

Comment: thanks! but my dialog won't show up when I press the button..:(

Comment: @key991117 can you please show me where you instantiate the CustomDialog and call `callDialog()`? Do you do this in an activity/fragment? If so -- please show me the activity/fragment's source code. Thanks.

Comment: @key991117 See my edited answer (scroll to the bottom). I explained how to create a DialogFragment in order to show the dialog as you require. Please mark my answer as correct, and upvote it if this helps.

Comment: I fixed it but still it won't show up..I think I made a mistake in getting data from server..I will check on my server and try again. thanks!

Comment: Hm the data you are retrieving shouldn't have any effect on your dialog showing up or not. If you'd like more help, please post your activity's code, where to dialog is called from.